issues joining / control two armatures with one mesh - Joining mixamo rig & universal human rig
For my primary mesh, I have been working with the universal human rig and to get fast and easy animations, I wanted to use Maximo as well. So I exported the universal human rig mesh I sculpted into Mixamo, imported that into blender then created a Mixamo controlled rig.
I want to keep my controls of the universal human rigged armature as well as the controls from the Mixamo armature.  Basically combining the two but being able to freely use each armature separately and have them both control one mesh? I just can’t figure out how to get them both to join/parent together. Reasoning why I want to use both armatures is because I like the face controls the universal rig offers but I want to be able to add in Mixamo animations to the rig so I don't have to manually rig each step for the animation
I’ve tried adding two armatures in the modifiers, transferring weight paint, mesh data. I’ve also tried to parent the rigs together or the meshes together. everything seems to lead to problems and not what I’m looking to achieve. I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Does anybody have any solutions that could help me.


You need to export the mesh with the armature only as an FBX. Delete any other meshes like eyelashes or eyeballs or teeth, etc cause Mixamo won't know how to rig those and give an error. When you upload to Mixamo the bones will keep the same names and your weight painting will stay the same. After you download the animation import it and assign the action to you any armature with the same naming scheme and hierarchy. You may also have to disable any IK switches.
